# How to generate SQL scripts at a specific location with JPA Tools and EclipseLink?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, dali

I have a project set up with EclipseLink 2.7.0 and I'm using Dali in Eclipse. I am trying to use the context menu to generate SQL scripts but I'm having trouble getting the generated SQL scripts to be output at my desired location.

The `persistence.xml` file contains the following:

```
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="src/main/resources/sql/postgresql/"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="051-createDDL.sql"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="050-dropDDL.sql"/>
```

To have the SQL scripts generated, I right-click on the project, and select **JPA Tools** > **Generate Tables from Entities…** then I select **Sql-script** in the schema generation dialog that opens.
Per [this documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_create_ddl_jdbc_file_name.htm#createddljdbcfilename), I was expecting the scripts to be made available under `src/main/resources/sql/postgresql/` with the names I've specified but the files keep getting created at the root of the project under names `dropDDL.sql` and `createDDL.sql`. It's as if what I've specified in `persistence.xml` is ignored. I'm starting to wonder whether its contents is even used at all.

I have tried:

- defining `eclipselink.ddl-generation` to all three allowed values (`create-tables`…), to no avail.
- using the equivalent `javax.persistence.schema-generation` properties, also to no avail.

Is there a subtlety that I'm not aware of? Or some additional configuration? Maybe that I'm totally mistaken and the properties have nothing to do with Dali ?

Answer (score 1):

It is a complete mess, but here is what you need:

- [`eclipselink.ddl-generation`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#BABHEJJI): This controls whether DDL generation happens at all.
- [`eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#BABCDHBB): This has to be set to either `both` or `sql-script` or no DDL will be written to any file anywhere.
- [`eclipselink.application-location`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#CACHGDEJ): This is set to the absolute path that will contain your DDL output files.
- [`eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-filename`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#createddljdbcfilename): This is a path terminating in a filename that is relative to the absolute path supplied by the value of your `eclipselink.application-location` property.  **If you do not specify `eclipselink.application-location`, then this property is ignored.**
- [`eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-filename`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#BABFEBCG): This is a path terminating in a filename that is relative to the absolute path supplied by the value of your `eclipselink.application-location` property.  **If you do not specify `eclipselink.application-location`, then this property is ignored.**

In your example, you are missing [`eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode`](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#BABCDHBB).

Comment: Even with this configuration (i.e. with `application-location` set to an absolute path and `ddl-generation.output-mode` specified), Dali keeps generating the files at the root of the project. I've given up entirely as I've initialized the database on this new project of mine. I've come to understand that the properties defined in `persistence.xml` are not taken into account when Dali generates tables from entities.